# IPhone need design idea for tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

i have a UITableView where i want one cell(database row) needs to be default,
So I am thinking of two options

1. in TableView upon clicking a cell, change accessoryType to mark just like ringtone selection in settings app
2. when user enters data, add an option (like radio button or segmented control) to make that cell (database row) as default one

I feel first option is good but we can implement code for that only in didSelectRowAtIndexPath but i need to jump to another view when user click on a cell.

So please give me an idea how to accomplish this

One idea iam thinking is adding an edit button but don't know whether its possible or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if i understand your question correctly , but according to what i understand you want a table view in which many values will be there , and you want one value to be default which can be changed later.

According to me these ways would be pretty good,

1. Changing the accessorytype of the tableViewCell. (Most common way)
2. Changing the Highlighted property of the cell on loading the tableView.
3. Adding some image then setting the image as the background view of the selected cell.
4. Adding custom image view (such as tick or something and adding to the cell).

this code can be put in the viewDidload so your default selected value appears.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you mean by default.  I'm assuming you mean already selected.  You might just want to set the accessoryType to the checkbox.  That would be Apple's way of doing it.

Comment: NO, 
in other view i need to read these values but i use one which has value for key "default" set to 1, and all others will have 0
so user should be able to select one cell and i update that cell's "default" value to 1